# Need some PHP help filtering socket data from an Asterisk PBX

Tags: php, sockets

Please forgive my ignorance.
I've got some PHP code that opens an AMI socket and does a ConfBridgeList for a specific bridge (8888).
This all works just fine but I need to filter the information displayed to only CallerIDName so I can see a complete list of names of participants.
After days of googling and playing with it, I'm no closer than I was when I started.
I'm not at all married to a table.  A simple list of names is fine...
Any help is much appreciated!
Pertinent code:

```
<?php
$ami = fsockopen("127.0.0.1", 5038, $errno, $errstr);
if (!$ami) {
echo "ERROR: $errno - $errstr<br />\n";
} else {
fwrite($ami, "Action: Login\r\nUsername: someuser\r\nSecret: somesecret\r\nEvents: off\r\n\r\n");
fwrite($ami, "Action: ConfbridgeList\r\nConference: 8888\r\n\r\n");
sleep(1);
$record = fread($ami,1024);
$record = explode("\r\n", $record);
echo "<META HTTP-EQUIV=Refresh CONTENT=\"20\">";
echo "<table border=\"1\" style='color: black;'>";
foreach($record as $value){
    if(!strlen(stristr($value,'Asterisk'))>0
    && !strlen(stristr($value,'Response'))>0
    && !strlen(stristr($value,'Message'))>0
    && !strlen(stristr($value,'Event'))>0
    && strlen(strpos($value,' '))>0)
    php_table($value);;
}

echo "</table>";

fclose($ami);
}

function php_table($value){
    $row1 = true;
    $value = explode("  ", $value);
    foreach($value as $field){
        if($row1){
            echo "<tr><td>".$field."</td>";
            $row1 = false;
        }
        else{
            echo "<td>".$field."</td></tr>";

            $row1 = true;

        }
    }
}

?>
```

This returns:

Conference: 8888

CallerIDNum: 8000

CallerIDName: Uncle Remus

Channel: SIP/8000-000001c6

Admin: No

MarkedUser: No

Muted: No

ListItems: 1

I would like to see only "Uncle Remus" in this example.
I'm grateful for any help.
Thank you!
Pat...

Answer (score 0):

```
function php_table($value){
    $row1 = true;
    $value = explode("  ", $value);
    foreach($value as $field){
        $tmp = explode(':', $field);
        if (tmp[0] == 'CallerIDName'){
            echo $tmp[1];
        }
    }
}
```

Is it some usefull ?